# JSON to Object convetion with arbit element in JSON

Tags: json, spring, rest, jackson

I have a very typical requirement to convert a JSON request in java objet in a Spring Boot Rest Application … 
JOSN format is something like

```
{
"memberId":1,
"memberPIIData":[{
"Address":"test",
"BOD":"12/12/12",
"card":"3333 3333 33333"
}],
"memberNonPIIData":[{
"firstName":"ser ffe",
"lastName":"werwer",
"email":"jjjj"
}]
}
```

where "memberPIIData" and "memberNonPIIData" both are not with fixed element. client can call this API with any number and name set for PII and non PII data. Client can add any arbitrary element in PII or not NON PII array , but that must be in  key:value format.

In that case how can I define object structure in Java (a spring boot micro-service application) so that requested JSON can be mapped with java object and logic can apply on request param name of PII or non PII data. 
(like if card is in the request some extra method need to called up with some business logic)

Any help will be highly appreciated....

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to define a DTO class.

```
class MyDTO {

    Integer memberId;
    List<Map<String, String>> memberPIIData;
    List<Map<String, String>> memberNonPIIData;

    // getter and setters

}
```

You can receive the json through  your handler using the below template.

```
@PostMapping
public void myHandler(@RequestBody MyDTO myDTO) {
    // your processing logic
}
```